# Tutorial for implementing a SharePoint Service Application based on a Windows Service

Tags: service-application

I'm looking for a tutorial or some other information on how to implement a SharePoint Service Application which is based on a Windows Service.

Unfortunately there is not much information to find about this topic. And most of the few example you find on the internet are for service applications using WCF service.

Answer (score 3):

You need to expose your service application using a WCF or ASMX "Service Application Endpoint", regardless of how you implement the "Service Instance" (in your case a Windows service).

Service applications are covered in detail over at [Spencer Harbar's blog.](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010sa2.aspx)
Andrew Connell has also put together some decent [guidance on custom service applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg543112.aspx).